# Firestore ou SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, flutter, firestore

Existe alguma diferença de criar uma aplicação em Flutter utilizando o Firestore ao invés do SQLite?

Porque a maioria dos tutoriais falam em CRUD com Firestore e não com SQLite (pensei que o Flutter era como o Android Studio, onde se podia utilizar o SQLite para a criação de apps).

Qual diferença em si do Firestore para o SQLite?

Answer (score 3):

Isso é como comparar laranjas com maçãs, cada um serve a um propósito, eles não são exatamente concorrentes, embora sejam um pouco. Conforme a outra resposta, muitas pessoas adotam em tutoriais para facilitar a explicação e acabam direcionando as pessoas a fazem algo errado por causa disso. Por isso eu sempre falo que deve tomar cuidado com conteúdo na internet, você não sabe se a pessoa adotou algo para te ajudar ou ajudar ele ter menos trabalho, ou memso se a pessoa sabe o que está fazendo.

## Firestore

É um banco de dados de nuvem, e controlado pela Google. Você acessa os dados se tiver uma conexão, a Google estiver ok, quiser te dar acesso aos dados e você pagar (sim, é grátis até certo ponto, não para todas situações, algumas pessoas podem se arrepender tarde demais por ter adotado essa tecnologia). Talvez na maioria dos casos não acontecerá porque em adota sem pensar bem geralmente não faz aplicações que vão exigir mais do que o básico. Além disso é um bando de dados para armazenar documentos, em muitos casos as pessoas usam para armazenar dados tabulares e relacionados.

## SQLite

É local, completamente livre, em todos os sentidos, não depende de terceiros, de conexão, tem bastante flexibilidade, é ótimo para dados tabulares e relacionados e geralmente faz o acesso via SQL. Obviamente que para trocar os mesmos dados de um dispositivo para outro precisa de algum mecanismo extra porque ele não é centralizado.

## A escolha

A escolha passa muito se quer algo local ou em nuvem, se pode lidar com as restrições de cada um, e principalmente se o tipo de dados que está usando são mais documentos ou mais dados variados relacionados.

Existem diversas diferenças nos detalhes, mas não é adequado falarmos de todas aqui, porque seria uma lista extensa, o mais importante é o modelo de acesso (documento X relacional) e de forma de acesso, além de como é licenciado e distribuído.

A minha experiência é que a maioria das pessoas fazem coisas tão simples com eles que mesmo que escolha a opção errada não deve afetar muito, mas para aplicativos mais importantes se torna necessário um estudo detalhado por alguém experiente para fazer a escolha mais adequada.

Comparar Flutter com Android Studio se torna mais complicado ainda porque aí está comparado bananas (um *stack* de tecnologia amplo) com colheres (um IDE).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar tanto Firestore quanto SQLite.

A galera costuma utilizar o Firestore pois ele é um banco NoSQL e basta você criar o banco no teu Firebase que tudo já está funcionado, ou seja, utilizam ele pois deixa as vídeo-aulas e tutoriais mais fáceis...

Sem contar que com ele você consegue utiizar de forma fácil a autenticação utilizando o Google e Facebook.

Já o SQLite é um banco "normal" e para utilizá-lo você precisa estruturar suas tabelas, criar selects e tudo mais, deixando assim a explicação mais complexa.

*Obs.: Caso for procurar, em Flutter utilizamos o SQFlite que é o plugin do SQLite.*